# How to request a permission on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I'm new to using Android Studio, just want to make a basic app for myself, and I can't request any permission on my phone, it just refuses automatically.
I'm using Kotlin but also tried in Java (as I studied Java years ago but never learned to code on Android).
My phone is a OnePlus Nord 2t (if that makes any difference), and is using API 33. My project has a minimum SDK of API 30.

I already made sure the build.gradle minSDK and targetSdk are ok, and added this line to the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
// also tried to add tools:node="replace" and tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" because I saw people mentionning it
```

Here's the whole code I have for now

```
package com.example.testpermissions

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Check if the permission is already granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Permission is already granted.
            Toast.makeText(this, "already ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "prompting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Permission is not granted.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted.
                Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Permission denied by the user.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used Toasts to see what's working or not, and all I have is "prompting" then "not ok", and the app continues running normally after that.

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: "My phone is a OnePlus Nord 2t (if that makes any difference), and is using API 33" -- `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not used on that version of Android or newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), you will see that:

> Note: Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect. If your
> app accesses other apps' media files, request one or more of these
> permissions instead: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
> READ_MEDIA_AUDIO. Learn more about the storage permissions that are
> associated with media files.

Therefore, if you require to access specific media files, you need to ask for a different permission.

- [READ_MEDIA_IMAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
- [READ_MEDIA_VIDEO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_VIDEO)
- [READ_MEDIA_AUDIO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, I kind of gave up on this because as I said I'm a newbie and only want a little app working for myself. I don't want to go deep in programming and yet here I am, spending hours just to access the damn files... Your solution helped me to get permissions, I can access the internal storage and find the file, but when I try to access it with FileInputStream, it says "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)". I don't understands how the read permission can be granted AND denied at the same time...

Comment: @chdarro - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such. Furthermore, you can edit your question with new details or ask a new question.